# Use findQuery with FixtureAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use a FixtureAdapter to load the data locally when I'm developing the app.

These is my Page model with Fixture data:

```
App.Page = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
    parent : DS.belongsTo('App.Page'),
    subpages : DS.hasMany('App.Page')
});

App.Page.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Home',
    subpages: [ 2, 3, 4 ]
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'About',
    parent: 1
},{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Contact',
    parent: 1
},{
    id: 4,
    name: 'Search',
    parent: 1
},{
    id: 5,
    name: 'Blog',
    parent: 2
}];
```

This is the code that returns all the Page objects in my Fixture

```
App.PagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Page.find();
    }
});
```

This is my App.store:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision : 11,
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});
```

This works great, but how do I return the root page?

When I change `return App.Page.find()` in `App.Page.findQuery(App.Page,{ id: 1 })` I get the following error:
`Uncaught Adapter is either null or does not implement 'findQuery' method`

-- UPDATE --

When I change `return App.Page.find()` in `App.Page.find({ name: 'Home' })` I get the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_create' of undefined`

I guess that is because my data isn't loaded at that moment. But I thought that Ember would handle that for me.

Comment: [`FixtureAdapter#findQuery`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L108-L120) calls [`FixtureAdapter#queryFixtures`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L42-L47), which has the comment "*Implement this method in order to query fixtures data*". So in debug, set a breakpoint at the `Store#findQuery` and check what you get from [`this.adapterForType(type)`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L745-L751)

Comment: Also, how are you defining your app `Store`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for Ember Data 0.13:

```
App.fixtureStore = DS.Store.create({
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
    queryFixtures: function(fixtures, query, type) {
      return fixtures;
    }
  })
});
```

And when testing be sure to do this:

```
App.store = App.fixtureStore;
DS.set('defaultStore', App.fixtureStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to define store:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision : 11,
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});
```

Note the **extend** instead of **create** and capital letter **S** in **Store**.
See [Ember Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-a-store/) for more info.